# css inline-block elements, last child to float left when using text-align:center on parent div

Tags: css, text-align

Here you have the code and demo version of the problem. 
if you see the last two black boxes are in center is there a way to make them show on left side ?

```
mainparent
{
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#ccc;
}
.boxes
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
  background:#000;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/axheladini/JxhP8/)

Comment: add this : #mainparent {text-align:left;}

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to break his original align for all boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just float them left ? (*and resize your container to fit them..*)

This way you have better control of the margins, since the `font-size` does not affect them (*nor the whitespace*)

```
#mainparent
{
    width:480px;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.boxes
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    background:#000;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/JxhP8/32/

---

**Update**

If you want the elements left aligned amongst themselves but center aligned in their container, you will need another element in the middle and some javascript..

Here is a jquery implementation

**html**

```
<div id="mainparent">
    <div class="centerized">
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        ..
        ..
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#mainparent
{
    background:#ccc;
}
.centerized{
    overflow:hidden; // to grow according to the boxes
    margin:0 auto; // to be centered in container
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
    // cache the repeatedly used elements
    // and fixed values
    var main = $('#mainparent'),
        centerized = main.find('.centerized'),
        itemWidth = main.find('.boxes').outerWidth(true);

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var fitItems = (main.width() / itemWidth) | 0;
        centerized.width(fitItems * itemWidth);
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/JxhP8/34/

Comment: what will happen this way when the scren will be bigger or smaller :)

Comment: because i want it to be responsive and in real website the parent div is 100% width.

Comment: but li elements are not centered now hmm

Comment: you can't have both conditions at the same time (*both aligned at center and aligned at left..*). You will have to use js to resize the container to exactly fit the contents and center the container..

Comment: @AXheladini, you need to include jquery (*if you still have a problem, please post the link to your live site so i can have a look*)

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS `#mainparent` `text-align` to `left`.

Comment: than child elements will not be centered inside parent div!

Comment: I guess you will have to go with @DaveRook's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have answers, an alternative is to use CSS Selectors

```
#mainparent
{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ccc;
}
.boxes
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    background:#000;
}

.boxes:nth-child(17)
{float:left; margin-left:21px;}

.boxes:nth-child(18)
{float:left; margin-left:9px;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JxhP8/12/)

You still have work to do to get the layout correct, it only works when you have a fixed number of boxes etc, but you may find this approach useful (or horrible to know not to use it again!)

Comment: this way last two elements go to the most left, thats not what i want!

Comment: i need it to be responsive. This way it will not look good on different screens. There might be some javascript solution for this!